# Runnin a thread inside a loop to sum numbers in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

I would like to get the current value of sum in the main function without waiting for the thread t1 to finish. But the code give below crashes for some reason. Please help.

EDIT: The real program that I'm writing to calculate a threshold value is given. The summation code immediately below just has the same problem as the real program I think.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<thread>
    #include<chrono>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    static int sum;


    void test()
    {
          sum = 0;
        while (sum<10)
        {

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            sum += 1;

        }

    }

    int main() {

        while (1) {

        thread t1(test);
         cout << "Thread id " <<t1.get_id()<< endl;
        cout << sum << endl;

        }


        return 0;
    }
```

The real code looks like this:

```
    #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<thread>
    #include<chrono>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    int maxThreshold = 0;
    vector<int> getThresholds(Mat srcImage)
    {
        int histogram[256] = { 0 };
        int pixelsCount = srcImage.cols * srcImage.rows;

        for (int y = 0; y < srcImage.rows; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < srcImage.cols; x++)
            {
                uchar value = srcImage.at<uchar>(y, x);
                histogram[value]++;
            }
        }

        double c = 0;
        double Mt = 0;

        double p[256] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            p[i] = (double)histogram[i] / (double)pixelsCount;
            Mt += i * p[i];
        }

        int optimalTreshold1 = 0;
        int optimalTreshold2 = 0;
        //int optimalTreshold3 = 0;

        double maxBetweenVar = 0;

        double w0 = 0;
        double m0 = 0;
        double c0 = 0;
        double p0 = 0;

        double w1 = 0;
        double m1 = 0;
        double c1 = 0;
        double p1 = 0;

        /*double w2 = 0;
        double m2 = 0;
        double c2 = 0;
        double p2 = 0;*/
        for (int tr1 = 0; tr1 < 256; tr1++)
        {
            p0 += p[tr1];
            w0 += (tr1 * p[tr1]);
            if (p0 != 0)
            {
                m0 = w0 / p0;
            }

            c0 = p0 * (m0 - Mt) * (m0 - Mt);

            c1 = 0;
            w1 = 0;
            m1 = 0;
            p1 = 0;
            for (int tr2 = tr1 + 1; tr2 < 256; tr2++)
            {

                p1 += p[tr2];
                w1 += (tr2 * p[tr2]);
                if (p1 != 0)
                {
                    m1 = w1 / p1;
                }

                c1 = p1 * (m1 - Mt) * (m1 - Mt);


                /*c2 = 0;
                w2 = 0;
                m2 = 0;
                p2 = 0;*/

                double c = c0 + c1 + 0 + 0;

                if (maxBetweenVar < c)
                {
                    maxBetweenVar = c;
                    optimalTreshold1 = tr1;
                    optimalTreshold2 = tr2;
                    //optimalTreshold3 = tr3;
                }


            }
        }

        vector<int> thresholds;
        thresholds.push_back(optimalTreshold1);
        thresholds.push_back(optimalTreshold2);
        //thresholds.push_back(optimalTreshold3);
        maxThreshold = optimalTreshold2;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000)); //dont run repeatedly//calculate every 3 seconds
        return thresholds;


    } 


    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

        while (1)
        {
Mat image, imgray;
            Capture(); //captures video frames and puts them in variable image


            namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
            imshow("Original", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

            cvtColor(image, imgray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


            //////thread//////
            std::thread otsuThread(getThresholds, imgray); //calculate otsu threshold which is intensive// cant call it outside teh while lopp because i need to pass get captured images
            otsuThread.detach(); // i dont want to wait for the thread to finish// 





            threshold(imgray, finalImage, maxThreshold, 255, THRESH_BINARY); // i want to use whtever value of threshold is at this instant



            namedWindow("Final", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
            imshow("Final", finalImage);                   // Show our image inside it.

            waitKey();                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I would like to get the current value of sum in the main function without waiting for the thread t1 to finish." then stop destroying thread object on every iteration of loop in `main()`

Comment: Are you **sure** you want to be creating an 'infinite number' of threads (none of which lives for very long, BTW)? That's what your code is trying to do, with the `thread t1(test);` line *inside* the `while(1)` loop!

Comment: If the variable is accessible by both threads, it is not necessary for one thread to wait for the other to complete.   It is, however, necessary to synchronise the threads to ensure that only one thread at a time reads or writes that variable.   For example, both threads lock a mutex, and only read/write the variable when they have gained the lock, and release the mutex when done - this ensures, if one thread has locked the mutex, that the other waits until the mutex is released, before reading/modifying the variable.

Comment: @Peter "Your program is probably crashing because it creates more threads" no, because `std::thread` is destroyed in joinable state. So it crashed at the first iteration

Comment: @AdrianMole The code creates just exactly one thread and crashes in destructor of `t1` at then end of the very first iteration. `std::terminate` is called and this behavior is well defined.

Comment: @Peter At the end of the first iteration, destructor of `t1` calls `std::terminate()`. There is no other iteration and, therefore, no other thread created. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/x2Ayx5zJgZlBK4o7.

Comment: @Peter main() does not create threads in a tight loop, it tries to create and immediately destroy a single thread in each loop iteration. Behavior you describe would be possible if OP would call `std::thread::detach()` before the end of that loop

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, indeed. But the point I was trying to make (albeit, not very well) was that OP *probably* wants to create the thread *before* the start of the `while` loop.

Comment: @AdrianMole May be, though I don't understand what for there is that endless loop. I vote to close until more details are provided.

Comment: @DanielLangr The idea is simple. I want to do some calculations that is very intensive(inside the test function).So I would like to run is as a thread. The value of the sum should be able to be read by the main function at any time. The test function however should not run continuosly, i.e i want the result, say, after every other x seconds. The whle loop in the main function captures frames in my code.

Answer (score 0):

even I don't know, what you want to do with this, you could change the content of your main-function to this:

```
// declare the thread only one time outside of the loop
thread t1(test);
while (1) {

    cout << "Thread id " <<t1.get_id()<< endl;
    cout << sum << endl;
    // let this main-thread sleep too, to not print after every nano-second
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

By the way: you should at least build a mutex or spin-lock around the incrementing and the get of the `sum`-object, to avoid race-conditions, in the case that you plan to make more complex stuff inside the thread.

Comment: "you should at least build a mutex or spin-lock" sounds like you should use a car or a vehicle. A mutex can be implemented as a spin-lock it still would be a mutex.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Would declaring `sum` as `std::atomic<int> sum;` be sufficient in this case? From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic): *If one thread writes to an atomic object while another thread reads from it, the behavior is well-defined*.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, it would be sufficient.

Comment: @Slava yeah, your right, but I mean with mutex something like `std::mutex`, which really blocks the thread and with spin-lock, something which makes busy-waiting with the help of, for example, `std::atomic`.

Comment: With `std::atomic` you do not need a mutex here

Comment: @Slava I only mentioned mutex too, because I don't know, whats still planed based on this code. Maybe it was planed to do more complex operations on structs or anything else, where a simple atomic is not enough anymore. I doesn't wantet restrictet this on this single snippet, so I tried to make the answer more common.

Answer (score -1):

Your code creates infinitive number of threads.

You must call t1.join() to wait for your thread or t1.detach() to end it without waiting. If you don't do it you will get debug error when thread goes out of scope.

Comment: That's not debug error, `std::thread` destructor calls `std::terminate()` if thread is joinable. And it does not create infinite numbers of threads, it tries to create and destroy a thread infinite times

Comment: maybe diferent compilers give diferent results in this case, if you don`t call detach or join and compile it with visual compiller, it will create window with message about debug error.

Comment: @Алексей This debug error is very likely caused by program calling `std::teminate`. Behavior of the program is defined and cannot (should not) depend on the implementation (compiler).

Comment: No, `std::thread()` documentation clearly says so. It is just your IDE behaviour to create a window when `std::therminate()` is called.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. The behavior of the program is actually **undefined**, since there is _data race_ on `sum`.

Comment: can you please share how to declare the thread outside of the loop and start it inside the loop. My intention is for the test function to sum the numbers until 10.But at the same time the main function should be able to get whatever sum is at any instant. However, i do not want to run the test function continuously since the processing is very intensive inside of it.